# Securing OpenSecureChannel messages and X509IdentityToken?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

Kindly clarify on the following queries about the OPC UA specification Part 4 Services,

1. From my understanding after the GetEndpoints Service messages, the client sends a OpenSecureChannel request to the server which means the request is signed or signed & encrypted according the security policy in the desired endpoint. I saw the following lines in the specification Part 4 Services, pg.no 33,

> The OpenSecureChannel request and response Messages shall be signed
>   with the sender’s Certificate. These Messages shall always be
>   encrypted. If the transport layer does not provide encryption, then
>   these Messages shall be encrypted with the receiver’s Certificate.

In this it is mentioned that the messages **shall** always be encrypted. How does it rely on transport layer ?

And I also see another description in the OPC Unified Architecture Book by Wolfgang Mahnke, Stefan-Helmut Leitner, Matthias Damm as follows,

> If the certificate is considered as trustworthy, then as the second
>   step an OpenSecureChannel request secured in accordance to the
>   Security Policy and the Security Mode is sent to the selected Session
>   Endpoint of the server. (Chapter 7, pg.no:213)

Here, it highlights that the message is secured in accordance to the Security Policy and Security Mode, so I request a clarification on the scenario if the security mode is sign?

Will the message be encrypted also?

2. In general, when the MessageSecurityMode is None then the SecurityPolicy ‘must’ be None? What is the exact usage of 'Invalid' MessageSecurityMode?
3. X509IdentityToken specification Part 4 Services section 7.35.4

> This token shall always be accompanied by a signature in the
>   userTokenSignature parameter of ActivateSession if required by the
>   SecurityPolicy. The Server should specify a SecurityPolicy for the
>   UserTokenPolicy if the SecureChannel has a SecurityPolicy of None.

In the first line it is mentioned that ‘if required by the SecurityPolicy’, what is context of ‘if required’ when the userTokenSignature is a required field for X509IdentityToken ? In the second line it is mentioned that a explicit Security Policy is required if the SecureChannel has a SecurityPolicy of None, where ‘None’ means no certificates are exchanged and so X509IdentityToken cannot be used, referring to the following lines in the same specification (Section 5.6.3 ActivateSession, pg.no: 40)?

> If the token is an X509IdentityToken then the proof is a signature
>   generated with private key associated with the Certificate. The data
>   to sign is created by appending the last serverNonce to the
>   serverCertificate specified in the CreateSession response.

For your kind information I use the specification released on November 2015 to study. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, the specification continues with "These requirements for OpenSecureChannel only apply if the securityPolicyUri is not None". So the answer is that a SecureChannel will both sign and encrypt the OpenSecureChannelRequest/Response for any MessageSecurityMode, except MessageSecurityMode.None.

For the second question, if MessageSecurityMode is None, then the Security policy is none. There is no usage of MessageSecurityMode.Invalid as far as I can find.

For the third question, if the securityPolicyUri is None, then no *application* certificates are exchanged. The client can provide a UserIdentity by a X509IdentityToken. The token consists of a X509Certificate and a signature. The signature is generated by appending the server nonce to the server certificate and signing with the user certificate's private key.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, can you also please clarify how the encryption of OpenSecureChannel messages depend on transport layer? With the third question, my query was the data to be signed is the server certificate (including serverNonce) received in the previous CreateSession Response, if the mode was None then what will be the data to be signed (because, in this case no application instance certificates are exchanged) ?

Comment: The X509IdentityToken consists of a third X509Certificate that identifies the user, not the client or the server's certificate.

Comment: To clarify, the encryption of the OpenSecureChannel messages does not rely on the transport layer. The OSC messages will be signed and encrypted for any MessageSecurityMode except 'None'.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on securing the OpenSecureChannel messages in None mode. Can you please site any references where the proof of signature for X509IdentityToken can be generated on the user certificate data itself !?  refering to your following comment, _**the signature is generated by appending the server's nonce to the certificate's data and signing with the certificate's private key.**_

Comment: From my understanding the userTokenSignature is a proof of the X509IdentityToken so I understand that the serverCertificate + serverNonce returned in CreateSession response is signed using private key of the user

Comment: I'm wrong. You are correct that the data to sign is the server cert + server nonce. So the original question is that the client does need to get the server cert from the endpoint description.

Comment: When server nonce is a sufficient challenge for generating userTokenSignature, why is the server certificate required ? Any